# Does the main site can't understand non-western?

Tags: discussion

I am getting this opinion after asking [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/156266/35909) on the main site that. Some users received it well. And many others are just down-voting and closing the question.

What is the issue with the question? It is expecting an answer from the people who experienced the same or from some standard practices of such people.

Is it because of the reason that the culture mentioned is absent in west, the question is taking down by people?

Is suggestions for a majority of women from many countries are not entertained there?

**Update**: It has been closed now.

Comment: To somewhat re-iterate my comment on the main question: The cultural standards in question also do not expect women to have any (intellectual, full-time, upper-class) career – which is also true for traditional Western culture. (Mind that for lower classes, everybody had/has to work hard to survive anyway; stay-at-home wives are in some sense a luxury.) Women adhering to these standards will indeed not be entertained here, but that’s because these standards expect them not to engage in the general topic of this site.

Comment: To the title, I'd say fully yes. Even as a European, the advice feels often wrong and "too US" (and often, answer begin with "Generally", "Normally" or "Obviously" and present something which is unheard of in (my parts of) Europe). It must be even worse for non-Western (and generally, for universities/countries with bad systems/corruption etc.)

Comment: @user111388 what feels non-European about the advice provided? The only answer suggests to distribute equally the household tasks among the couple, and to take advantage of "formal regulations stimulating a healthy work-life balance". This definitely applies to Europe, probably even more than to the US. In fact, the answer mentions Scandinavia, and everything in the answer can be applied to Germany too.

Comment: @wimi: This answer is absolutely (western) European. Other answers are not. (I was referring only to the title of this meta question, not about the linked question.)

Comment: @user111388 that might be true. But the only way to fix it is to provide answers from other perspectives... US users of course have US experience.

Comment: @wimi: Yes, of course. But there are, as of today, not enough, say, Indians (or Europeans, or East Asians) that Indian answers can be usefully provided. I am not saying that this problem can be easily solved (although it would be a beginning if people would write in their answers that their knowledge is about the US and not the "whole world") but I agree with the title of this meta question.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I'm surprised the question is still open and still has a nonnegative score.

> What is the issue with the question?

I think the comments make the issues pretty clear:

- This is not an academic question; many careers require long hours for low wages during the early years. For example: bankers, lawyers, and doctors.
- This is similarly unrelated to any particular gender or race; single fathers in the West face similar pressures to what you describe (well, except for "periodic cycles" I guess). Indeed, some may find your assumptions offensive.
- Even setting aside these troubles, it's not clear what sort of answers are possible. Your actual question is "how do superwomen find time to deal with academic activities?" and the only possible answer is "they work hard and efficiently." (Though, I did think Wetenschaap's answer was excellent).

> Is the main site intolerant to non-western?

If you search the [India](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) tag alone, you will find 77 questions, many of which are open. So, we have a pretty good record of handling non-Western questions (though our user base does seem to be predominantly western). I realize it can be frustrating to ask a poorly-received question, but I don't think accusing us of intolerance and bigotry is a defensible reaction.

Comment: **This is not academic question**. Please check the stipends and salaries in academic and non-academic contexts.   Then you will come to know, it can be academic. Remaining professions are not same in this context.

Comment: I am well aware of how much academics get paid :-)

Comment: Then, how can you compare with remaining professions?  some scholars get 8 thousand per month. Can they hire maid, like any other profession?

Comment: In the US, first-year medical residents _gross_ [$5000/month](https://www.partners.org/Graduate-Medical-Education/Residents-Clinical-Fellows/Salary-Benefits/Salary.aspx) and carry [$250,000](https://www.credible.com/blog/statistics/average-medical-school-debt/) in student loan debt. For first year lawyers, the situation is [only slightly better](https://work.chron.com/average-starting-salary-law-school-students-7716.html). So I don't think any of the professions I listed are hiring maids early in their careers.

Comment: I didn't ask about US. India can be different. https://www.legallyindia.com/topical/d/2726-what-is-the-starting-salary-for-a-law-graduate

Comment: The current version of your question (v5) makes no mention of India, other than in a tag. At any rate: I stand by my answer; not going to debate it further. Cheers!

Comment: @hanugm:  In any country, there are better and worse paying professions than academic ones, even if you restrict yourself to intellectual, full-time, upper-class careers. The salary doesn’t this make this academia-specific.